# Best way to generate integer numbers in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to generate integer numbers and I'm looking for the best way to do this. Example:

```
?- number2(N).
N = 0;
N = 1;
N = 2;
...
(and so on)
```

Now I'm simply using `length/2`:

```
number2(N) :- length(_, N).
```

But I think that there should be some better way (without creating temporary list). I could probably write some code myself basing on code of `length/2` but I'm looking for solution that employs already existing, built-in predicates. Is there any built-in predicate that would work better than `length/2`? I couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: `length/2` is a good solution for this task. SWI-Prolog has an extension where you can use `between(0, infinite, N)`, but this completely breaks the types of this predicate, and it is not portable. Therefore, I recommend to use `length(_, N)` instead. The list overhead is negligible for most search tasks which you typically tackle with iterative deepening this way, say, for numbers that typically are well below 100, and it also works for thousands or even millions of elements. Only then would I consider custom code for this.

Comment: Also, check this out: If you are using SWI-Prolog, you can define a `goal_expansion/2` rule that automatically replaces `length(_, N)` by `between(0, infinite, N)`. Try it: `goal_expansion(length(Ls,L), between(0,infinite,L)) :-  var_property(Ls, fresh(true)).`. This completely avoids any auxiliary list.

Comment: ... but, sadly, as @false points out below, also replaces calls of `length/2` that must not be replaced. Thus, a more specific property is needed here, like `singleton`, which is currently not yet provided by SWI-Prolog.

Comment: length(_,N) only generates natural numbers (N) but not integers (Z).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to top your solution ; and probably it is not worth the effort. After all, there are now three suggestions that all are incorrect for one case or another:

```
?- time( (number2_gk(N), N == 10000) ). % your original
% 20,002 inferences, 0.007 CPU in 0.007 seconds (99% CPU, 3006132 Lips)
N = 10000 

?- time( (number2_cc(N), N == 10000) ). % quadratic overhead
% 50,025,001 inferences, 28.073 CPU in 28.196 seconds (100% CPU, 1781945 Lips)
N = 10000 

?- time( (next_integer(N), N == 10000) ).
% 20,002 inferences, 0.011 CPU in 0.011 seconds (100% CPU, 1822247 Lips)
N = 10000
```

However, `number2_cc(-1)` and `next_integer(-1)` simply loop, `length/2` actually should produce a domain error, like SICStus [and many other systems](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/length) do.

As you can see, CC's solution is worse than your original one.

Also the suggestion by mat produces different behavior in the following situation:

```
goal_expansion(length(Ls,L), between(0,infinite,L)) :-
   var_property(Ls, fresh(true)).

as(N) :-
   length(L,N),
   phrase(a, L).

a --> [a], a.
a --> [].
```

The goal `as(N)` now loops instead of enumerating all `N`.

If you really insist on an improvement, consider the following tail-recursive solution using `library(clpfd)`:

```
nat(N) :-
   nat(N, 0).

nat(N, N0) :-
  N #>= N0,
  (  N = N0
  ;  N1 is N0+1,
     nat(N, N1)
  ).

?- time( (nat(N), N == 10000) ).
% 1,850,152 inferences, 0.544 CPU in 0.545 seconds (100% CPU, 3399793 Lips)
```

Which is only an improvement for queries like the following. Otherwise it is just a waste of resources.

```
?- N in 1..2, nat(N).
```

Comment: @mat: provided you stop using `infinity` for `between/3`... which works in SWI only.

Comment: @mat: please provided a clean, determinate version for `nat(3)`!

Answer (score 3):

To keep between/3 pure, i.e. only with integer arguments,
I have started providing the following predicate above/2
in a library (for the source code see [here](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/blog/docs/05_run/05_frequent/advanced/arith.html)):

```
/**
 * above(L, X):
 * The predicate succeeds for every integer X above the integer L.
 */
% above(+Integer, -Integer)
```

So if you really want to generate integer numbers,
and not natural numbers, you can use:

```
gen_int(X) :-
    above(0, Y),
    (X is Y; X is -Y-1).
```

The above will give 0, -1, 1, -2, etc.. . If you want to
generate natural numbers including zero, you can use:

```
gen_nat(X) :-
    above(0, X).
```

The above will give 0, 1, 2, etc... The names gen_int/1
and gen_nat/1 are inspried by SICStus Prolog, see [here](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.3.0/html/sicstus/lib_002dbetween.html).

Hope this helps.

Bye

Answer (score 2):

A tail-recursive alternative to Carlo's solution is:

```
next_integer(I) :-
    next_integer(0, I).

next_integer(I, I).
next_integer(I, J) :-
    I2 is I + 1,
    next_integer(I2, J).
```

A sample query:

```
?- next_integer(I).
I = 0 ;
I = 1 ;
I = 2 ;
I = 3 ;
...
```

You can also easily start from an integer other than zero. For example:

```
?- next_integer(-5, I).
I = -5 ;
I = -4 ;
I = -3 ;
I = -2 ;
I = -1 ;
I = 0 ;
I = 1 ;
I = 2 ;
I = 3 ;
...
```