# prolog -- generate integers "unwindably"

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to define lambda calculus terms with De Bruijn indices. I'm using swi prolog on OS X.

If I use a `zero|successor` representation of a natural number, I can interactively complete a partially specified term.

```
nat(zero).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).

debruijn2(N)         :- nat(N).
debruijn2(ap(M, N))  :- debruijn2(M), debruijn2(N).
debruijn2(lambda(M)) :- debruijn2(M).
```

for instance, `Z` and `X` unify with `zero` in `ap(Z, X)`.

```
?- debruijn2(ap(X, Z)).
X = Z, Z = zero .
```

But, using `length` to check numbers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063693/best-way-to-generate-integer-numbers-in-prolog) produces a type error unless the argument to `debruijn` is just an integer.

```
debruijn(N)          :- length(_, N).
debruijn(ap(M, N))   :- debruijn(M), debruijn(N).
debruijn(lambda(M))  :- debruijn(M).
```

The query `debruijn(X).` succeeds and `X` unifies with `0`.

```
?- debruijn(X).
X = 0 .
```

However, the query `debruijn(ap(Z, X)).` fails as if `length(_, ·)` is irrevocably constraining its second argument to be an integer.

```
?- debruijn(ap(Z, X)).
ERROR: Type error: `integer' expected, found `ap(_2944,_2946)' (a compound)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] throw(error(type_error(integer,...),context(...,_3008)))
ERROR:    [8] debruijn(ap(_3036,_3038)) at <...>:2
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR:
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
   Exception: (8) debruijn(ap(_2362, _2364)) ? creep
```

Why is `length/2` producing a type error instead of just failing to apply to the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because Prolog tries to evaluate `length/2` predicate during search. According to [manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2), it raises an error if the second argument is bound to a non-integer. That differs from simply failing the check.

You can use [`catch/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=catch/3) to turn failure into a false predicate:

```
debruijn(N)          :- catch(length(_, N), _, false).
debruijn(ap(M, N))   :- debruijn(M), debruijn(N).
debruijn(lambda(M))  :- debruijn(M).
```

Manual says that recovering from an exception is quite slow, though. I'm no Prolog expert by any means, so maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Is there a trick, like introducing an extra variable or something, that could be used to get failure rather than an exception in the base case of `debruijn/1`?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet extended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative running on SWI-Prolog without using expensive calls to `length/2` and `catch/3`:

```
debruijn(N)         :- simple(N), nat(N).
debruijn(ap(M, N))  :- debruijn(M), debruijn(N).
debruijn(lambda(M)) :- debruijn(M).

nat(0).
nat(I) :-
    nat(1, I).

nat(I, I).
nat(I, J) :-
    I2 is I + 1,
    nat(I2, J).
```

The `simple/1` predicate succeeds if its argument is not instantiated to a compound term. It's a legacy predicate that was never standardized but still found in some Prolog systems (e.g. it's a library predicate in SWI-Prolog and a built-in predicate in SICStus Prolog).

A difference to the `length/2` based solution that may or may not be relevant to your use case is the behavior when `debruijn/1` is called with a negative number. In this case, this solution will go into a loop and eventually an error but `length/2` will throw an exception that the `catch/3` wrapper will convert into failure.

Comment: *generating* all DeBruijn terms *fairly* looks like a fairly non-trivial challenge... maybe it'd lead to a checking predicate with improved termination properties as well (e.g. `debruijn(0)` succeeds, then goes into infinite loop)... I thought about generating the terms for top index N while counting down to 0 from N, for each N increasing from 0 up, but even then the number of terms for each N seems to be  infinite...