# A Function that lists all combination of addition and its answer, in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to code a function that lists all combinations of `(X, Y, Z)` such that `X + Y = Z`.

#### Example input/output:

```
?- combination(X, Y, Z)
X = Y,     Y = Z,       Z = 0;
X = 0,     Y = Z,       Z = s(0);
X = Z,     Z = s(0),    Y = 0;
X = 0,     Y = Z,       Z = s(s(0));
X = Y,     Y = s(0),    Z = s(s(0));
X = Z,     Z = s(s(0)), Y = 0;
...
```

I don't want to leave variables in the answer as `plus(0, Y, Y). plus(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :- plus(X, Y, Z).`  returns:

```
?- plus(X, Y, Z).
X = 0,
Y = Z ;
X = s(0),
Z = s(Y) ;
X = s(s(0)),
Z = s(s(Y)) ;
X = s(s(s(0))),
Z = s(s(s(Y))) ;
```

I also do not want to inclement `Z` unless all combinations of `(X, Y, Z)` is listed when `Z` is constant. That is, I want to avoid results to be like

```
X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0;
X = 0, Y = s(0), Z = Y;
X = 0, Y = s(s(0)), Z = Y;
X = 0, Y = s(s(s(0))), Z = Y;
...
```

#### My (naive) trials

```
combination(0, 0, 0). %C1
combination(s(Y), X, s(Z)) :- combination(X, Y, Z). %C2
combination(s(X), Y, Z) :- combination(X, s(Y), Z). %C3
```

I thought at least logically these clauses can induce all combinations:

```
   (C1) -> (0, 0, 0) 
-> (C2) -> (1, 0, 1) 
-> (C3) -> (0, 1, 1) 
-> (C2) -> (2, 0, 2) 
-> (C3) -> (1, 1, 2)
-> (C3) -> (0, 2, 2)
-> ...
```

However, what I get is an error.

```
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 0.8Gb, global: 0.1Gb, trail: 38.4Mb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 5,031,935, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 5,031,928
ERROR:   Possible non-terminating recursion:
ERROR:     [5,031,935] user:combination(<compound s/1>, _40261270, _40261272)
ERROR:     [5,031,934] user:combination(<compound s/1>, <compound s/1>, _40261300)
```

I am novice at this language and have no clue what is missing. Any advice for modification, or just information to related language design is appreciated. I apologize in advance that my thinking process might be seen mess to you.

Answer (score 0):

Without Peano:

```
sums(I1, I2, Sum) :-
    incrementing(0, 1, Sum),
    between(0, Sum, I1),
    I2 is Sum - I1.
```

... using `incrementing` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73584150/

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- sums(I1, I2, Su).
I1 = I2, I2 = Su, Su = 0 ;
I1 = 0,
I2 = Su, Su = 1 ;
I1 = Su, Su = 1,
I2 = 0 ;
I1 = 0,
I2 = Su, Su = 2 ;
I1 = I2, I2 = 1,
Su = 2 ;
I1 = Su, Su = 2,
I2 = 0 ;
I1 = 0,
I2 = Su, Su = 3 ;
etc.
```

Comment: Using your code, I was able to make it in peano version! Many thanks for your help.